# Repeating table header on every page with Pechkin

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf, pechkin, tuespechkin

I'm trying to include the header (`thead`) of a table on the top of every page generated by Pechkin (wrapper for wkhtmltopdf), but it doesn't seem to work at all. Is this feature even available or am I missing something?

I've tried including the following into the pages CSS:

```
table { page-break-after: auto; }
tr { page-break-inside: avoid; page-break-after: auto; }
td { page-break-inside: avoid; page-break-after: auto; }
thead { display: table-header-group; }
tfoot { display: table-footer-group; }
```

Comment: You're trying to insert HTML into the header of the page? Can you post your code please?

Comment: @Vash Nono, I'm trying to repeat the header of the tables after every page break. I've got a table with thousands of entries and when printed as PDF, it obviously spans accross multiple pages. So on the top of every page, the table header should be visible as you can do it with normal css (code above)

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the answer is that this isn't possible. The only thing you can probably do is put the table header in the PDF header.